# Extract number in square brackets / Sencha-touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I use the sliderfunction in Sencha Touch 2

my Container looks as follows:

```
   xtype: 'container',
   height: 149,
   minHeight: 480, 
   ui: 'dark', width: 283, 
   items: [ { 
       xtype: 'sliderfield',
       border: 4,
       docked: 'top',
       height: 42,
       itemId: 'alphaSliderField', 
       width: 280,
       label: 'Profilgewichtung', 
       labelWidth: '44%', 
       value: [ 0 ],
       increment: 0.5,
       maxValue: 1 
    },
```

Now I want to use the value of it which could be 0 , 0.5 and 1. The problem is that the number is embraced by square brackets and I can only use it whitout these brackets.

Can anyone please tell me how could I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract value in three ways:

- `<your component>.getValue()[0]`
- `parseFloat(<your component>.getValue())`
- `<your component>.getValue().toString()`

Comment: you helped me finding the solution, thx ... <your component>[0] worked